# Xcode 5.1 Not seeing my remote repository

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to setup a remote repository on a linux box for an application we inherited via CD.  But when I tried to push the source to the new repository the repository line says “No Remotes”.  I do see stuff for the MailCore stuff which I didn’t setup.

```
Source Control-> Push
Push local changes:
MOPASource No remotes
MailCore    origin/master
IOSPorts    origin/(detached from 2b..)
Libetpan    origin/(detached from 6c..)
```

This is what I did:
On the linux box the SA installed git and then I created the git repository.
    cd ~account/archives
    mkdir –p 775 MOPA
    git init

```
Xcode->Preferences Accounts tab I added the repository information successfully to Xocde:
Address:  ssh://acount@X.X.X.X/home/archives/MOPA/.git
User Name:  account
Password:  account password
Description: .git
```

After making sure all local files were committed I tried to push to the remote and got the No remotes problem.

I then tried to push on the command line thinking that would work, but I git says nothing is on the linux box.

```
git remote add origin account@x.x.x.x/home/account/archives/MOPA/.git
```

On the remote I see this:
    lasarus3:/home/account/archives/MOPA>git status
    # On branch master
    #
    # Initial commit
    #
    nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

```
Should I just ssh the local .git directory to the remote site?  What am I missing?
```